About the product of closed subgroups in a Lie Group
In general, my problem is that I don’t fully understand the relationship between the differential and group structures of a Lie group. If this were in the context of a vector space, I would know the answer. I have a specific question that has revealed this broader issue I’m struggling with.
I have a Lie group of dimension 8 (as a real manifold) and two closed subgroups of dimension $4$ denoted by $H_1$ and $H_2$ so that $H_2 = g H_1 g^{-1}$ where $g\in G\setminus H_1$ and I also know that $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\}$ (while e is the identity element).
I believe that, if true, the following question might also apply to Lie groups of arbitrary dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$. My question is: can I ensure that $H_1$ and $H_2$ generate $G$ in the sense that every element of $G$ can be expressed as a product of elements from $H_1$ and $H_2$? If this is not the case, how close is this situation to being true? My first thought is that the product $H_1 H_2$ should be a Lie group of dimension $8$ but I don't know if I am missing something.
I think that the product $H_1H_2$ should be another Lie group of dimension 8 contained within G. If both $H_1H_2$ and G are connected, I believe $H_1H_2$ should be equal to $G$ but I am not entirely sure if this argument is completely valid.
Hope I can find some help! Thanks!

I think it would be helpful, if you share your thoughts: why do you think $H_1H_2$ is an 8 dim. Lie group (you meen $ {gh \mid g \in H_1 , h\in H_2 }$ right?)? Why should this be argument enough for the product to be G? And what is the connection to the "connection"-property (sorry for the pun)? I think this information are highly useful for people who might be able to answer your question...
